# 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'dawdw' in 'field list'

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I am trying to add new values to the database but an error appears

why does this error occur?

[image]

My code

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=HOSTNAME,
    user=USERNAME,
    passwd=PASSWORD,
    database=DATABASE
)
crsr = conn.cursor()
crsr.execute(f"INSERT INTO ord (type, link, sitename, telgramname) VALUES (dawdw, awdawd, awdwada, adwwa)")
conn.commit()
crsr.close()
conn.close()
```

[image: [database structure]()]
[image]

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
crsr.execute(f"INSERT INTO ord (type, link, sitename, telgramname) VALUES (dawdw, awdawd, awdwada, adwwa)")
```

Because `dawdw` is not in quotes, it expects that to be the name of another column.

You apparently intended those values to be strings, so they should be in quotes.

```
... VALUES ('dawdw', 'awdawd', 'awdwada', 'adwwa')
```

Comment: Like this ?
```crsr.execute(f"INSERT INTO ord (type, link, sitename, telgramname) VALUES ('dawdw', 'awdawd', 'awdwada', 'adwwa'))")```

Comment: @Andrey That statement has too many closing parentheses.